# operator python parameter

Tags: python, function, parameters

In Python, how can I pass an operator like `+` or `<` as a parameter to a function which expects a comparison function as a parameter?

```
def compare (a,b,f):
    return f(a,b)
```

I have read about functions like `__gt__()` or `__lt__()` but still I was not able to use them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [operator module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/operator.html) is what you are looking for.
There you find functions that correspond to the usual operators.

e.g.

```
operator.lt
operator.le
```

Answer (score 5):

[use operator module for this purposes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html)

```
import operator
def compare(a,b,func):

    mappings = {'>': operator.lt, '>=': operator.le,
                '==': operator.eq} # and etc. 
    return mappingsp[func](a,b)

compare(3,4,'>')
```

Comment: Why the `lambda`?  Don't you just want `{'>':operator.lt, '>=':operator.le, ... }`

Comment: just forget to check without +1 for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda condition as a method parameter:

```
>>> def yourMethod(expected_cond, param1, param2):
...     if expected_cond(param1, param2):
...             print 'expected_cond is true'
...     else:
...             print 'expected_cond is false'
... 
>>> condition = lambda op1, op2: (op1 > op2)
>>> 
>>> yourMethod(condition, 1, 2)
expected_cond is false
>>> yourMethod(condition, 3, 2)
expected_cond is true
>>>
```